# Status of DualLinearProgramming

Tags: mathematical-optimization

`DualLinearProgramming` is referenced in this tutorial

[`tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLinearProgramming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLinearProgramming.html)

It exists in Mathematica 12, but lacks documentation.

I guess that it has been superseded by `LinearOptimization`.

Is there any information available about what it does, and how the same might be achieved with `LinearOptimization`?

*UPDATE*

It still exists in V13.1.  `?` returns a link (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DualLinearProgramming.html), but this leads to "Document not found".

It is no longer mentioned in the tutorial linked above.

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understand it, [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLinearProgramming.html) says in "Finding Dual Variables" section

> The dual maximizer can be obtained from LinearOptimization using the "DualMaximizer" solution property

and gives an example

```
primal = LinearOptimization[ 3 x + 4 y, {x + 2 y >= 5, 1 <= x <= 4, 1 <= y <= 4}, {x, y}, {"PrimalMinimizerRules", "DualMaximizer"}]
```

> `{{x -> 1, y -> 2}, {{2, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {}}}`

, where `{2, 1, 0, 0, 0}` are the optimal values of the dual variables. All that works in 13.1 on Windows 10.